# Create Item list for DropdownButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dropdownbutton

I'm back with another issue with the DropdownButton.

The DropdownButton is not enabled. I found this in api.flutter.dev

> If the onChanged callback is null or the list of items is null then
> the dropdown button will be disabled, i.e. its arrow will be displayed
> in grey and it will not respond to input.

Here is my code now:

```
return new DropdownButton<String>(
                            hint: new Text("Select Agency"),
                            value: _currentAgency,
                            onChanged: changedDropDownAgency,
                            items: snapshot.data.docs.forEach((document) {
                              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: document.data()['name'],
                                child: new Text(document.data()['name']),
                              );
                            }),
                          );

void changedDropDownAgency(String selected_agency) {
    setState(() {
      _currentAgency = selected_agency;
    });
    globals.selectedAgency = selected_agency;
  }
```

The forEach loop runs fine and in debug mode I can see that there is data in the document object. I don't know how to debug the DropdownButton code to see why the button is not active. Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach()` on Iterables does not return any value (see: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html), and thus `items` is null and the `DropdownButton` is disabled. Use `map` instead (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Iterable/map.html). Example:

```
snapshot.data.docs.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((document) {
    return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: document.data()['name'],
        child: new Text(document.data()['name']),
    );
}).toList(),
```

Comment: thank you for your response. However, when I use your code I get the following:  The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#5bb78):
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>?'

Comment: I've edited my answer, please see if this works. I am explicitly telling dart what the return type of Map should be.

Comment: The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#b9a5e):
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Select Agency. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 855 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'

Comment: return new DropdownButton<String>(
                            //hint: new Text("Select Agency"),
                            value: _currentAgency,
                            onChanged: changedDropDownAgency,
   items: snapshot.data.docs
   .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((document) {
   return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: document.data()['name'],
                                child: new Text(document.data()['name']),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          );

Comment: `_currentAgency` seems to have the value of 'Select Agency' and none or 2 or more of your `DropdownMenuItems` seem to have this value. You should use `hint` instead and set the initial value (so `_currentAgency`) to null.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did set _currentAgency to null and even removed hint:  but I still get the error. I will do some more research. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I changed the line value: document.data()['name']  to  value: document.id  and now it works. Go figure.

Comment: Oh. Glad you could figure it out!

Comment: I'm not smart enough to have figured it out. It was more like stumbling onto the answer. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Comes with expierence! You might want to accept this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers